# Error tras importar un proyecto con maven en eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Acabo de importar un proyecto de la universidad con maven en eclipse y me da el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es solo en MacOs, en windows funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Ese problema no es de en qué OS compilas sino de la versión de Java que estás usando en cada caso.

Comment: Del sitio en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66974846/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-with-java-16-j-l-classformaterror-access

Comment: Actualiza Java.